# The value Array.push'd to parent-scoped value differs in and out of Array.forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I expect `FOO[0].price` to be `1`, but it is `9999.99` after `allRows.forEach` is done running. When I output `rules` at the end of the `forEach` loop, the `price` value is expected, but at the end of the loop it's mutated the values of all objects in the array to match the last value. I don't understand this behavior. Is it scope-related?

```js
const priceListIndex = [{
  columnIndex: 2,
  usergroup: 'anon',
  label: '<100',
  low: 12,
  high: 99
}, {
  columnIndex: 3,
  usergroup: 'anon',
  label: '100+',
  low: 100,
  high: 9999
}];

const allRows = [
  ['FOO', null, '$1.00', '$2.00'],
  ['BAR', null, '$9999.99', '$8888.88']
]

const rules = {};

allRows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
  const sku = row[0];
  console.log(`Value of var "sku" is now ${sku}.\n`);

  row.forEach(
    (cellVal, index) => {
      const rule = priceListIndex.find(
        (priceList) => priceList.columnIndex === index
      );

      if (rule && cellVal[0] === '$') {
        const price = parseFloat(cellVal.slice(1));

        if (!rules[sku]) {
          rules[sku] = [];
        }

        document.write('<pre><code>' + (`Adding ${rule.label} @ ${price} for ${sku}`) + '</pre></code><br />');

        rules[sku].push(Object.assign(rule, {
          price
        }));
      }
    },
  )
});

document.write('<pre><code>' + JSON.stringify(rules) + '</code></pre>');

document.write('<p>Expected <code>FOO[0].price</code> to be 1, but it is 9999.99</p>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` mutates the first argument. So `Object.assign(rule, {price})` will overwrite the `price` property in `rule`. To avoid mutation, create a new object:

```
Object.assign({}, rule, {price})
//             ^ new object that gets mutated
```

Comment: Thank you! I appear to have become too reliant on my spread operators in ES6 and forgot the "low level" way to solve this problem.

Comment: fyi: with spread syntax, it would be `{...rule, ...{price}}`.